# vue-property-decorator: data change doesn't trigger `emit` event

Tags: vue.js, vue-property-decorator

I created this [selection field](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-example-xdph35?file=/src/main.js). I want to reflect the selected `fruits` from the `SelectAll` component on its parent component, so I created a component event (`@Emit("fruitsSelected")`) for it -- it shall return the `selectedFruits` string array to the the `Parent.vue`.

The code works fine if `fruits` are selected one by one. But, `$emit` doesn't fire up if the `Select All` button is used in the drop-down. I'm not sure why. Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tao's answer using the `@Watch` decorator is correct but just wanted to add why your original code didn't work, and that is because your `toggle()` method was not tied to any emit. Only your `returnSelectedFruits()` was emitting anything.  This should also work:

```js
@Emit("fruitsSelected")
  toggle() {
    if (this.likesAllFruit) {
      this.selectedFruits = [];
    } else {
      this.selectedFruits = this.fruits.slice();
    }
    console.log(this.selectedFruits);
    return this.selectedFruits;
  }
```